# how to get navigation controller to UIview iphone

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to navigation from UIView.

Comment: To Kiran, please be a little more elaborate in your question. And to the users who answered with "I don't understand", this comment section would be a place for that response.

Comment: I can't understand your question ?? can you describe your question .. so that I can answer your question

Comment: I can only assume the question was supposed to be "Is it possible to _get parent_ navigation _controller_ from UIView?" +1 for the -1 (-:

Answer (score 0):

See [How to get parent navigation controller in UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935186/how-to-get-parent-navigation-controller-in-uiview)