# How to get parent navigation controller in UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, ios4

I have created a `UITabBarController` in my app delegate.
where each tab bar item holds a different `UINavigationController` that loads a custom `UIViewController` with a NIB (using `-pushViewController:`).
Inside one of the navigation controller, I load a custom `UIView` class with a custom NIB also.
This view is loaded multiple times inside the `UIViewController`.

The custom `UIView` has a `UIButton`, that on the event of touching it, I want to push a new `UIViewController` on the stack.
Problem is that I 'lost' the `UINavigationController` that holds the `UIViewController`.
I know I should use delegates, but haven't figured out who should which class should be the delegate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: delegate vould be better. the delegate should be defined in your view class and should be implemented by your owner. Secondly the owner property should be in UIView not in UIViewController.

Answer (score 3):

Neither .navigationController or .tabBarController will be available for a UIView or UIViewController that's been created but not pushed onto a stack

Either create a property on your View (or ViewController) class that is a UIViewController that is provided optionally after initialization or you could add a third argument to `initWithNibName:bundle:`

```
@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController
{ 
    UIViewController *owner;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIViewController* owner;

@end
```

Then in the owner ViewController:

```
CustomViewController *cvc = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibNamed:nil bundle:nil];
cvc.owner = self;
```

It's too bad .parentViewController is read-only, this would be the sensible place for this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
That's what I did, i've setup a property and after allocation and initialization I've set the owner as 'self'.
But when use the getter [self owner] in e.g. viewDidLoad i get (null).
If i do it in the owner ViewController: [cvc owner] i don't get (null).

Comment: Are you assigning the owner before adding it to the parent subview?

Comment: Yes. I also release the view after adding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this using `UIApplication` class. Using this class you can find which `viewController` is placed at first. Here is the solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585881/finding-the-rootviewcontroller-in-ios) for your problem.