# Finding the rootViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, uiapplication

In ShareKit, the code needs to determine where the rootViewController is so it can show a modal view. For some reason, the code is failing in iOS 5:

```
    // Try to find the root view controller programmically

    // Find the top window (that is not an alert view or other window)
    UIWindow *topWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    if (topWindow.windowLevel != UIWindowLevelNormal)
    {
        NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
        for(topWindow in windows)
        {
            if (topWindow.windowLevel == UIWindowLevelNormal)
                break;
        }
    }

    UIView *rootView = [[topWindow subviews] objectAtIndex:0];  
    id nextResponder = [rootView nextResponder];

    if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
        self.rootViewController = nextResponder;

    else
        NSAssert(NO, @"ShareKit: Could not find a root view controller.  You can assign one manually by calling [[SHK currentHelper] setRootViewController:YOURROOTVIEWCONTROLLER].");
```

This is hitting the assert.

What is wrong with simply using the following code, instead?

```
rootViewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
```

This seems to be working fine. Will it fail under some conditions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can rely on `window.rootViewController` b/c you don't have to set it. You can just add a subview to the window. The following seemed to work fine:

```
id rootVC = [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] nextResponder];
```

Comment: Thanks. The rootViewController is set, in this case. It's not clear to me that just setting that automatically makes it the rootViewController for the purpose of this ShareKit code.  This is a universal app, and in the iPhone code, the rootViewController is a subclassed UITabBarController. I should add that I also have a UIAlertView and UIView added as subviews to the application window. (I can show either one or both of them regardless of which view from the tabbarcontroller is showing.) Your code returns the UIAlertView as the objectAtIndex:0. I could just iterate through the rest, I guess.

Comment: if you're setting it in your app then it will definitely work. I didn't know if you were creating a library for others to use where you can't rely on the `window.rootViewController` being set.

Comment: @XJones, what if window.rootViewController is not set? is there any other way to reliably get the current view controller?

Comment: XCode always warns that rootViewController must be set, so it should be a safe assumption

Answer (score 1):

Swift way to do it, you can call this from anywhere:

```
/// EZSwiftExtensions - Gives you the VC on top so you can easily push your popups
public var topMostVC: UIViewController? {
    var presentedVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
    while let pVC = presentedVC?.presentedViewController {
        presentedVC = pVC
    }

    if presentedVC == nil {
        print("EZSwiftExtensions Error: You don't have any views set. You may be calling them in viewDidLoad. Try viewDidAppear instead.")
    }
    return presentedVC
}
```

Its included as a standard function in:

https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
UIViewController * rootViewController = (UIViewController *)[[[UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow subviews] firstObject];
```